# Modules appear as themes in themes page

Tags: 7

Not serious but interesting. I entered into the themes page and besides themes I also found there modules.

Any suggestion what can cause this behavior?

[image]

Comment: hmmm interesting, if you switch to a default D8 template does this still happen?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning (updated the Q - It's a D7 site... But I tried it anyway --- It stays the same)... :|

Comment: I have seen this before. It had to do with an corrupt module or theme directory that I fixed by re-downloading from d.o.. I'll check my notes.

Comment: FYI — I couldn't find my notes on the matter. I would start troubleshooting by removing all non-core themes first to see if it removes the module listing from admin/appearance. FWIW, the "hacked" module https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked will confirm whether your core and contributed modules are as they should be.

Comment: check you your directory it happen only when we add modules files in theme folder

Comment: check to see any aliases created for modules folder by wrong

Comment: I am not sure I understand @Mhmdgomma ... Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modules listed there are [dependencies](http://themeforest.net/item/dawn-responsive-drupal-theme/4685987#item-description__module-dependencies) of the Dawn theme, and when we look at the [Changelog](http://themeforest.net/item/dawn-responsive-drupal-theme/4685987#item-description__changelog) there are entries like: `- Added jQuery Update, Honeypot modules`.

There is no way for a theme to define module dependencies (you'd need an installation profile for that), so my best guess would be the theme creators packaged the modules within the theme. 
Normally I would have checked that for you, but it is a little harder with commercial themes. You should browse through your Dawn theme folders and see if the modules are nested in a sub-folder somehow. (Perhaps there is even a README explaining you should move them?)

The reason they are listed as themes is because modules and themes both provide a *.info file containing the details, and only the folder they are in is used to distinguish between module or theme. Since the module / theme detection in Drupal can scan multiple folders deep (eg. Views UI module is a subfolder of the Views module), it probably detects these modules's .info files and assumes they are themes since they are in the `sites/all/themes` folder.

Comment: You were right. Thank you for your answer. I just started another bounty. You might want to take a look and get another bounty from me in the same week.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have placed your modules in theme folder (sites/all/themes). I think it will be the issue.

Comment: No man, the themes are in sites/all/themes and the modules are in sites/all/modules

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be "recreate". So:

1. set up a brand new Drupal 7 installation (ie D7_bis) aside your main installation.
2. check the themes page (F5)
3. Copy one contributed/custom module to D7_bis installation

Loop steps 2 and 3, till you recreate the bug.

Once bug is recreated, you know which module is breaking your main Drupal installation. In case you cannot recreate the bug, you should investigate somewhere else (maybe a broken drupal core?)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, but the reason of this bug was in node.js.

The reason is in *.info files, which drupal looks in all folders, no matter if he found it earlier. I used gulp gulp-sass and gulp-sourcemaps in my theme, some of them now contain a little *.info file with author info, like README file. So, Dupal didn't understand that and there is problem. There is one more problem, site can crash on some page cause of this.

The easiest way to fix it, going to theme folder where you use node.js packages and execute command:

```
find node_modules/ -name '*.info' -type f -delete
```

If you always use node.js packages in theme, better to add this command into package.json file at the end

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "find node_modules/ -name '*.info' -type f -delete"
}
```

After `npm install` command this will be executed automaticaly. You can see real example [here](https://github.com/Niklan/Glisseo/blob/7.x-1.x/STARTER/package.json#L26-L28).